# Get the id I am passing YII

Tags: yii

Im still new to yii and havent been really familar in everything so what i want to do is get the value of the id (xwrg/ixxdfgx.xxx?r=vintages/view&id=2) say my id here is 2 and echo it

Please I hope someone can help

Comment: Simple u can get it using $variable=$_GET['id'] and echo $variable

Comment: If you are new i recommend [reading very nice guide to yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also, if you use [named parameters](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url#using-named-parameters) in your urlManager rules (main/config.php):

```
'/vintages/<id:\d+>' => 'Vintages/Index',   // i.e. http://example.com/vintages/15
```

Then you can access them like this:

```
public function actionIndex( $id )
{
    echo $id;    // Outputs 15
}
```